# InputStream Infinit Loop

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, jersey

I'm trying to upload a File from Android to a Tomcat server running Jersey. I'm packaging it inside a Post Request.

This is what I do in Android:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    String pathToFile = params[1];
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    httpPost.addHeader("Cookie", "sessionToken=~session");
    try {
        httpPost.setURI(new URI(url));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        File file = new File(pathToFile);
        if(!file.exists())
            return null;
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
        entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response.getStatusLine().toString();
```

In the server I have the following:

I receive an InputStream of the type "org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream" and while reading it, the read goes back to 1024 after reaching the end of the file.

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response uploadStorageFile(@Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh, @FormDataParam("file") 
InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){
    System.out.println(uploadedInputStream.getClass().getName());
    String uploadedFileLocation = fileDetail.getFileName();
    long size = fileDetail.getSize();
    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream);

    String output = "File uploaded to : ";

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.jpg"));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If the length of the file is 8192, the cycle goes like this:
1024,2048,3072,4096,5120,6144,7168,8192,1024 -> why?

Note: I have tried with the condition at -1.

Can anybody figure out what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried `>-1` ?

Comment: I'm afraid that > -1 nor != -1 work. 
The value of read goes in this order: 1024,2048,3072,4096,5120,6144,7168,8192,1024.
It never hits -1 nor 0.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I don't want to connect an InputStream with an OutputStream.

I just want to grab a file, package it into a packet and unpack it at server side...Thank you for commenting

Comment: `read(byte[1024])` reads 1024 bytes into byte buffer and returns 1024 to `read` variable..what did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting it to return -1 at EOS as you correctly said but it never returns -1. 
Is my While loop incorrect?

Comment: Would this help : https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-965

Comment: Indeed @JonathanDrapeau. What I will do is send the size of the stream in the packet and then use that size to pass the data from the stream to the File.
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

Since that helped you solve your problem, your latest comment indicates that [this bug was responsible.](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/965)

> Both methods "read" on ReadMultiStream class violate contract of the implemented
>   interface java.io.InputStream. Javadoc states, that -1 should be returned at the
>   end of the stream, but ReadMultiStream class returns -1 only for the first call
>   (at the end of the stream), all subsequent calls throw an exception instead.
>   This problem could be simulated by sending a stream of characters over web
>   service and wrapping it to the java.io.BufferedReader on the client side. When
>   the stream doesn't end with a new line character, then the usual usage of method
>   readLine fails.
>
> Fix Version/s:    2.2.6

Comment: It helped identify the Problem, the solution itself is not yet identified.
I found a simple way to solve it (I'll make an answer), however there seems to be some serious flaws on the ReadMultiStream.

Comment: also that bug does not exactly match the one I'm facing. The bug I'm experiencing causes the stream to go around in a loop never returning -1 (or an exception).

The bug report you provided gives -1 at the first time, and the following returns an exception, quite different but it helped me see that ReadMultiStream is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jonathan Drapeau, @*boxed*| the problem was identified. ReadMultiStream violates the java.io.InputStream Interface.

The solution was rather simple, server side:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response uploadStorageFile(@Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh,     @FormDataParam("file") 
InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){
System.out.println(uploadedInputStream.getClass().getName());
String uploadedFileLocation = fileDetail.getFileName();
long size = fileDetail.getSize();
// save it
try {
            //test.jpg for test purposes
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.jpg")); 
    IOUtils.copy(uploadedInputStream, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

String output = "File uploaded to : ";

return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

Multiple tutorials were teaching to work the inputstream (server-side) as I provided in the question, for this reason I don't know if it's a recent bug.